# Ruby Active Model serializer custom serializer for same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-api, active-model-serializers

lets say I have a method as follows

```
def index
            
            applications = Application.all
            
            render json: applications, each_serializer: ApplicationIndexSerializer, status: 200
end
```

now this works and it returns me my custom serializer, but if I want to add custom keys to the payload like {data: application} it stops working.

however when I change the render method to

```
render json: {meta: {}, data: applications}, each_serializer: ApplicationIndexSerializer, status: 200
```

it throughs an error or the serializer does not get hit.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```rb
render json: applications, each_serializer: ApplicationIndexSerializer, meta: {}, status: 200
```

Comment: Did not work. I need the payload to look something like this

`{
    "meta": {
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
        },
}
`